# Как изменить цвет нумерации строк в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, datagrip

Есть множество настроек цвета самого кода/папок и прочего, но никак не могу найти где изменить цвет нумерации строк

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать таким способом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть настройка по пути:

```
 "Settings::Editor->Color Scheme->General::Code->Line number"
```

[Ссылка](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000062024-Line-numbers-are-grey-Is-this-configurable-in-any-way-) на первоисточник.